# Plotting system of linear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have a system of two linear equations here which I want to plot:

```
tan(x*y + 0.1) - x^2 = 0
0.5*x^2 + 2*y^2 - 2 = 0
```

But I wasn't able to express 1st function of system as `y = some_function(x)`.

So are there any other ways to plot this system of equations?

Comment: You mean *non-linear equations*. Try `ezplot`

Comment: Oh, it really is. Thanlks :)